# Automatically defining a variable in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

Depending on what I'm working on, I routinely define variables (e.g., `f = Foo.last`) when I open `rails console`.

Is there any way to do this automatically in my development environment?

For what it's worth, I'm using pry.

I can do this, but the session will exit:

```
$ rails c <<EOF
heredoc> f = Foo.last
heredoc> EOF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're fine with instance variables, you can add those to `~/.pryrc`

```
@f = Foo.last
```

With local variables this won't work, because they're local to their scope (hence the name).

What I do myself, is have all of the "setup" commands in a separate text file. Then in the new rails console, I just paste it.

- I don't have to re-type the same definitions with every console restart
- No pollution in the global config file
- Local variables with nice short names (that is, without the `@`)

Comment: Nice, this is probably close enough.  One amendment I would make is that pry picks up `.pryrc` in my Rails repository which is preferable to `~/.pryrc` for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Excellent, simply `c = Codebase.last` works in `.pryrc`.

Comment: @ErikNomitch: Hm, what version of pry do you have? Mine doesn't pick up local `.pryrc`, and doesn't export local variables from the global one.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to Sergio's suggestion of instance variables, you can also define methods in `.pryrc`:

```
def f
  @_f ||= Foo.last
end
```

I'm not certain this has all of the semantics you want, but it works for me.

Comment: Thanks, `--exec` would be perfect but since I need to launch pry via `rails console` I'm not sure how to pass it.  I'm using the `pry-rails` Gem.

Comment: Actually I was saying that you *can* define instance variables, because locals won't work. :)

Comment: Right you are, @SergioTulentsev. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @ErikNomitch Sorry about that. I've dug into pry-rails a bit and don't see a ready equivalent to `--exec` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

i poked around for a way to do this for a while and the best i've come up with is a way to set multiple variables in one line, at least. (keeping in mind that i do not want to use instance variables, and i want to be able to overwrite them, so methods wouldn't work):

in `~/.pryrc`:

```
# f, b, u, s = setup
def setup
  f = Foo.last
  b = Foo.bar
  u = User.find(5)
  s = u.settings.email_settings
  [f, b, u, s]
end
```

and so on.

---

i also found a post that covers abstracting the method approach, if you don't need to be able to overwrite them: http://kevinkuchta.com/_site/2014/09/load-useful-data-in-rails-console/